# expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token

Tags: c++, enums

I usually use enums to keep two arrays consistent by defining them like following:

```
enum foo {
    ZERO = 0,
    ONE,
    TWO,
};

int int_array[] = {
    [ZERO] = 0,
    [ONE] = 1,
    [TWO] = 2
};

char *str_array[] = {
    [ZERO] = "ZERO",
    [ONE] = "ONE",
    [TWO] = "TWO"
};
```

This code compiles fine for `c`, but throws following error when used in a `cpp` module.

```
expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token
```

Error is for each line in both array declarations. What's the problem here?

Comment: Short answer, this is not valid `c++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ does not support the so-called designator. Initialization that is allowed in C.

So the compiler issues a message.

In C++ you have to write just the following way

```
int int_array[] = { 0, 1, 2 };

const char *str_array[] = { "ZERO", "ONE", "TWO" }; 
^^^^^^
```

Comment: Isn't it a GCC extension? Or is it standard in C99 and above? I'm talking about C, BTW.

Comment: @CoolGuy The designator initialization was introduced in the C99. Maybe GCC also has its own language extension. I do not know.

Comment: @CoolGuy: gcc introduced this as an extension before C99 was released for `struct` members and arrays. It was added to the standard with a slightly different syntax with C99. Not added to the standard was to specify a range of indexes. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits

Answer (score 1):

It's not valid syntax for C++. You can initialize arrays in following way:

```
int int_array[] = { 0, 1, 2 };

char *str_array[] = {
    "ZERO",
    "ONE",
    "TWO"
};
```